# How to send out a large XML file to downstream services

Tags: xml, apache-spark, message-queue

I have a service which calls an external API to get a large xml file, does some filtering on this xml and sends out the new xml to multiple downstream services.

I am wondering how to achieve this. Should I split the file into multiple small files and send out through some tools? Or, should I use Spark directly? Or, should I use message queue to send out the message in the xml file line by line?

I will be appreciate if you have any suggestions or advice. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It usually depends on what kind of downstream services you are sending to. few offer compression techniques where you can wrap your big xml message into byte message, and receiver can convert it back to original xml

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That could be a wise option to reduce traffic.